# How one model can notify another model for specific property has changed?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-observing

Context, an iOS app using UIKit and MVC.

**Model A** has a singleton object, and one of its property value (`foo` in this case) can be changed during the runtime. **Model B** has a property, Model C, that is initialized using the property value of Model A.

```swift
class ModelA {
    private(set) var foo: CustomObjectClassName

    static let shared = ModelA()
}

class ModelB {
    private var bar: ModelC

    init() {
        self.bar = ModelC(ModelA.shared.foo)
    }

    // TODO: Observer `foo` value change in Model A and then
    // reinit ModelC to replace the old `bar` object
}
```

What is the common design pattern or mechanism that should be used to let Model B know about property change in Model A and re-initialize its own property?

I found two patterns that can be used; however, the more I read about them, they seem to be designed for communication between Model and Controller.

- NotificationCenter (Notification & Observer)
- Key-value Observing

**Related Information**

- Using Key-Value Observing in Swift, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift
- NotificationCenter, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

Comment: Use the property observer and the delegate call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for El Tomato comment, delegation can be a pattern be used.

A delegation pattern would work since in my case Model A is only used by a single entity Model B.

```
protocol ModelADelegate {
    func fooDidChange() -> Void
}

class ModelA {
    public var delegate: ModelADelegate?

    private(set) var foo: CustomObjectClassName {
        didSet {
            delegate.fooDidChange()
        }
    }
   
    static let shared = ModelA()
}

class ModelB, ModelADelegate {
    private var bar: ModelC

    init() {
        ModelA.shared.delegate = self

        self.bar = ModelC(ModelA.shared.foo)
    }

    func fooDidChange() {
        self.bar = ModelC(ModelA.shared.foo)    
    }
}
```

Comment: Does ModelC has other properties that an instance of  ModelB can change or are all ModelC objects the same?

Comment: Model C contains a property, Model A

Comment: Then why is it a property of ModelB if all instances are exactly the same, why not make it a property of the singleton to save some memory?